# Angular ReactiveFrorm: Should setValue trigger ngModelChange

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="register()">
    <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" (ngModelChange)="updateErrors('username')" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <button size="large" type="button" (click)="form.get('username').setValue('User')">Set username</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click the "Set username" button the value of `username` changes but the `updateErrors` method is not called.

Should it be? Maybe it should not but I do not understand something about `ngModelChange` event... (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix ngModel and reactive forms.  When using forms, you can listen on changes with

```
  this.form.valueChanges
     .subscribe(evt => {
        console.info(evt)
     });
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe: [6 Ways to Unsubscribe from Observables in Angular](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f)

Comment: Thank you very much!